# How do i declare props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio

```js
import "./Sidebaroptions.css";
import { Avatar } from "@material-ui/core";

function Sidebaroptions({ src, url, title }) {
    return (
        <div className="sidebaroptions">
            { src && <Avatar className="sidebaroptions_avatar" src={src} />}
            { url && <img
                className="sidebaroptions_image"
                src={url}
                alt=""
            />}
            <h4>{title}</h4>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Sidebaroptions;
```

[Failed to compile.

/Users/Prometheus/mpn/src/Components/Sidebar.tsx
TypeScript error in /Users/Prometheus/mpn/src/Components/Sidebar.tsx(8,18):
Property 'url' is missing in type '{ src: string; title: string; }' but required in type '{ src: any; url: any; title: any; }'.  TS2741

```
 6 |         <div className = "sidebar">
 7 |             <div className = "sidebar_top">
```

> 8 |                 <Sidebaroptions
> |                  ^
> 9 |                        src = {"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/81557989?v=4"}
> 10 |                        title = {"Gabriel Wiliiams"}
> 11 |                 />

[Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1WFK.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do i declare props?

By using a type argument with `React.FunctionComponent` (alias `React.FC`) or `React.Component`.

`React.FC` is for function components:

```
interface ExampleProps {
    src: string;
}
const Example: React.FC<ExampleProps> = ({src}) => {
    // ...
};
```

`React.Component` is for `class` components (you can also define your state type):

```
interface ExampleProps {
    src: string;
}
interface ExampleState {
    something: number;
}
class Example extends React.Component<ExampleProps, ExampleState> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            something: 42,
        };
    }
    // ...
    render() {
        const {src} = this.props;
        const {something} = this.state;
        return <div>{src}, {something}</div>;
    }
};
```

*(I've used declared interfaces there, but you can also use inline types.)*

---

Re the code you've posted, that's a function component, so you'd use `React.FC`. I typically use arrow functions since they're (slightly) lighter-weight and you don't need the things traditional functions have, so:

```
import "./Sidebaroptions.css";
import { Avatar } from "@material-ui/core";

interface SidebaroptionsProps {
    src: string;
    url: string;
    title: string;
}
const Sidebaroptions: React.FC<SidebaroptionsProps> = ({ src, url, title }) {
    return (
        <div className="sidebaroptions">
            { src && <Avatar className="sidebaroptions_avatar" src={src} />}
            { url && <img
                className="sidebaroptions_image"
                src={url}
                alt=""
            />}
            <h4>{title}</h4>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1WFK.jpg here is the code and error im getting

Comment: @GabrielWilliams - To improve the question, please use the "edit" link on the question.

Comment: @GabrielWilliams - I've added to the end of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the properties `src` and `url` are not always required for your component to work. You can make the fields optional by using `?`

```js
interface SidebaroptionsProps {
    src?: string;
    url?: string;
    title: string;
}

const Sidebaroptions: React.FC<SidebaroptionsProps> = ({ src, url, title }) => {
    return (
        <div className="sidebaroptions">
            { src && <Avatar className="sidebaroptions_avatar" src={src} />}
            { url && <img
                className="sidebaroptions_image"
                src={url}
                alt=""
            />}
            <h4>{title}</h4>
        </div>
    )
};
```

or by providing default values:

```
function Sidebaroptions({ title, src = "", url = "" }) {
    return (
        <div className="sidebaroptions">
            { src && <Avatar className="sidebaroptions_avatar" src={src} />}
            { url && <img
                className="sidebaroptions_image"
                src={url}
                alt=""
            />}
            <h4>{title}</h4>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Sidebaroptions;
```